# PHP proper use of session_start

Tags: php, session

When the web app starts, it will connect to DB and store the information as sessions variables. To get only the data at the beginning of the application.

The problem is that the users list is also a session variable. So in the login.php I have to add `session_start()` again when the user put the correct username and password?

**I think my solution is:**

- `Web server run -> session_start()` and get all the data needed.
- When the client run the app, there's no user logged in therefore the index.php will redirect to login.php. No session_start() because it as already started and after the correct username and password, change session variable "username" or "ID" to the username logged in.
- When the client log out, unset session variable "username".

What do you think about this solution, is this a right use of session in PHP?

Comment: Session variables are per user so it would be a bad idea to store a user list as a session variable. Also the session needs to be started on every request in which it will be used.

Comment: session_start() function should be on first line if possible. That is recommended in almost every book I have read.

Comment: `session_start` must be called on every page that reads or writes session data. It has nothing to do with server start.

Comment: @apokryfos The app will connect to DB and after that operate stand-alone, so I have to store the users list in session variable. If not, I have to search in XML files for the users always when someone try to login

Comment: @BackSpace The session is used to store data for an individual user so you cannot use it in the way you are suggesting.

Comment: @apokryfos Right, makes sense. One last question: The server connects to DB Server, save the data in XML files that stay local (in the server app). So when someone try to login, a method to search for that login in the XML file is called and check if login is correct. After that, a session is created and store all the info of XMLs files, for that user session. This is the best solution? We need to put in session data, because the server app can't have a database and we can't go always through the XML files when the user needs some info

Comment: What you're describing feels like caching. Instead of doing all the implementation on your own you can find some sort of library which deals with caching (and ideally with file caching as an option). I'd suggest you use a framework (like Laravel). The learning curve is a bit steep but it's worth it.

Comment: @apokryfos I'm going to read about that framework. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the session is started then you don't have to start it again just use this session to save data and to check login, it will work.

Comment: Yeah that's my point. But sometimes when I do ajax request to Controllers, example PainelConfigurationController.php, if I use the session data, I need to put "session_start()" in the beginning of the file. Is that correct?